# Python Paramiko timeout with long execution, need full output

Tags: python, ssh, timeout, paramiko

There's lots of topics touching on part of the title, but nothing that quite satisfies the whole thing.  I'm pushing a command on a remote server and need the full output after a long execution time, say 5 minutes or so.  Using channel I was able to set a timeout, but when I read back stdout I got only a small portion of output.  The solution seemed to be to wait for channel.exit_status_ready().  This worked on a successful call, but a failed call would never trigger the channel timeout.  Having reviewed the docs, I theorize that's because the timeout only works on a read operation, and waiting for exit status doesn't qualify.  Here's that attempt:

```
channel = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
channel.settimeout(timeout)
channel.exec_command(cmd)  # return on this is not reliable
while True:
    try:
        if channel.exit_status_ready():
            if channel.recv_ready():  # so use recv instead...
                output = channel.recv(1048576)
                break
        if channel.recv_stderr_ready():  # then check error
            error = channel.recv_stderr(1048576)
            break
    except socket.timeout:
        print("SSH channel timeout exceeded.")
        break
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        break
```

Pretty, ain't it?  Wish it worked.

My first attempt at a solution was to use time.time() to get a start, then check start - time.time() > timeout.  This seems straightforward, but in my present version, I output start - time.time() with a fixed timeout that should trigger a break...and see differences that double and triple the timeout with no break occurring.  To save space, I'll mention my third attempt, which I've rolled up with this one.  I read on here about using select.select to wait for output, and noted in the documentation that there's a timeout there as well.  As you'll see from the code below, I've mixed all three methods -- channel timeout, time.time timeout, and select timeout -- yet still have to kill the process.  Here's the frankencode:

```
channel = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
channel.settimeout(timeout)
channel.exec_command(cmd)  # return on this is not reliable
print("{0}".format(cmd))
start = time.time()
while True:
    try:
        rlist, wlist, elist = select([channel], [], [],
            float(timeout))
        print("{0}, {1}, {2}".format(rlist, wlist, elist))
        if rlist is not None and len(rlist) > 0:
            if channel.exit_status_ready():
                if channel.recv_ready():  # so use recv instead...
                    output = channel.recv(1048576)
                    break
        elif elist is not None and len(elist) > 0:
            if channel.recv_stderr_ready():  # then check error
                error = channel.recv_stderr(1048576)
                break
        print("{0} - {1} = {2}".format(
            time.time(), start, time.time() - start))
        if time.time() - start > timeout:
            break
    except socket.timeout:
        print("SSH channel timeout exceeded.")
        break
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
        break
```

Here's some typical output:

```
[<paramiko.Channel 3 (open) window=515488 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x888414cL (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>], [], []
1352494558.42 - 1352494554.69 = 3.73274183273
```

The top line is [rlist, wlist, elist] from select, the bottom line is time.time() - start = (time.time() - start).  I got this run to break by counting the iterations and breaking at the bottom of the try after looping 1000 times.  timeout was set to 3 on the sample run.  Which proves that we get through the try, but obviously, none of the three ways that should be timing out works.

Feel free to rip into the code if I've fundamentally misunderstood something.  I'd like for this to be uber-Pythonic and am still learning.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something that might help, though I'm still in the midst of testing.  After struggling with timeouts of various types including a catch-all timeout for Python, and realizing that the real problem is that the server can't be trusted to terminate the process, I did this:

```
chan = ssh.get_transport().open_session()

cmd = "timeout {0} {1}\n".format(timeouttime, cmd)

chan.exec_command(cmd)
```

The server times out after `timeouttime` if `cmd` doesn't exit sooner, exactly as I'd wish, and the terminated command kills the channel.  The only catch is that GNU coreutils must exist on the server. Failing that there are alternatives.

Comment: What worked for me was a variation on the above: 'timeout -s SIGKILL <timeout value> <cmd>', otherwise program was not killed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same kind of issue. I think we can handle it with signalling. http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

Here is a plain dumb example to show how it works.

```
import signal, time                          

def handler(signum, frame):                  
    pass                                     

# Set the signal handler and a 2-second alarm
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)       
signal.alarm(2)                              

# This is where your operation that might hang goes
time.sleep(10)                               

# Disable the alarm                          
signal.alarm(0)
```

So here, the alarm is set to 2 seconds. Time.sleep is called with 10 seconds. Of course, the alarm will be triggered before the sleep finishes. If you put some output after the time.sleep, you'll see that program execution resumes there.

If you want the control to continue somewhere else, wrap your hanging call in a try/except and have your handler function raise an exception.

Although I'm pretty sure it would work, I haven't tested it yet over paramiko calls.

Comment: My research ran in the same direction, but I am getting "ValueError: signal only works in main thread", though I'm not knowingly using threads in my code.  Either some module is forking the process or this is a bug.  Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah I realized too python only supports signals in the main thread. If you get that message, then I guess something spawns threads at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problem calling the exec_command from the channel, instead I use directly the exec_command from the ssh connection and call the channel of the std output, the code that works for me is like **myexec**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import paramiko
import select

def myexec(ssh, cmd, timeout):
  stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
  channel = stdout.channel
  stdin.close() #As I don't need stdin
  channel.shutdown_write() #As I will not write to this channel

  stdout_chunks = []
  stdout_chunks.append(stdout.channel.recv(len(stdout.channel.in_buffer)))

  # chunked read to prevent stalls
  while not channel.closed or channel.recv_ready()
        or channel.recv_stderr_ready():

    # stop if channel was closed prematurely,
    # and there is no data in the buffers.
    got_chunk = False
    readq, _, _ = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [], timeout)
    for c in readq:
      if c.recv_ready():
        stdout_chunks.append(stdout.channel.recv(len(c.in_buffer)))
        got_chunk = True
      if c.recv_stderr_ready():
        # make sure to read stderr to prevent stall
        stderr.channel.recv_stderr(len(c.in_stderr_buffer))
        got_chunk = True
    if not got_chunk \
           and stdout.channel.exit_status_ready() \
           and not stderr.channel.recv_stderr_ready() \
           and not stdout.channel.recv_ready():
      # indicate that we're not going to read from this channel anymore
      stdout.channel.shutdown_read() # close the channel
      stdout.channel.close()
      break    # exit as remote side is finished and our bufferes are empty

  # close all the pseudofiles
  stdout.close()
  stderr.close()
  return (''.join(stdout_chunks), stdout.channel.recv_exit_status())

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('remotehost', username='remoteuser', password='remotepassword')
rtrval = myexec(ssh, 'remotecomand', 5*60)
ssh.close()
print rtrval
```

I use Debian 8 and Python 2.7.13, good luck.